# Proof there is no lower bound for the totient function.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I wish to show there is no constant $c$ such that $ c n \leq \varphi (n) $, is this proof correct?.

From Euler's identity for the zeta function we have:

$$ \prod \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) = \frac{1}{\zeta (1)} $$

where the product is over all primes. We conclude the product approaches $0$. This means, for every constant c greater than $0$ there we can give a certain $k$ such that.

$$ \frac{\varphi(n_k)}{n_k} \leq c $$

where $n_k$ denotes the multiplication of the first k primes. This is as required.

Comment: Are you in my number theory class in UNAM?

Comment: anyways, I asked this question yesterday here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143024/does-a-positive-constant-nu-exist-so-that-varphin-nu-cdot-n-for-all-n

Comment: I guess I am in your number theory class in UNAM. Are you the guy who asked this during the class?. Ah... the world's a tissue.

Answer (score 0):

Without using divergent series, your argument can be modified this way:

Define $a_m$ to be the product of the first $m$ prime numbers. 
Now calculate $\varphi(a_m)/a_m$ and see what happens as $m\to\infty$.